# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project

Tags: eclipse

when i'm working in eclipse juno and trying to save grails file this error occured

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'My_Project_name'.
DONT_CARE
```

what is this error ??

Thanks

Comment: please point the exact error from problems tab. if not visible enable it from window->show view ->problems.

Comment: the Problem window is empty ... there are no problems

Answer (score 5):

Try this, goto Project tab, then properties, then click Java Build Path then Add Library, then Android Classpath Container, then select your project, then Hit Finish

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. In changing the name of my main project (altering the classpath), a dependent project was no longer associated with my project, so to resolve the issue I had to go to the properties, and add back the project to the Java Build Path.

Comment: I removed all libraries, saved and added them again. worked! thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I added this question and answering on my own as I could not find an
>   answer on Stackoverflow and it may benefit someone else
>
> Answer is:
>
> On your project "project", right click -> Properties>Builders Remove
>   the missing builder Source
>   http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/28894/

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and finally hit the solution by changing the order of libraries on build path.

Go to   Build Path-->configure build path--> on top make JRE system library --> Then MVN/Gradle dependencies--> Then Ur project src/main/test/resources folders.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading latest lombok jar and configuring it with the eclipse worked for me..
lombok: https://projectlombok.org/download

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32294680)

Comment: Thanks it fixed my problems by downloading the last version of lombok, and removing any spaces from the path of Eclipse Directory

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for solution. The problem in my case was that src/test/java was specified as a source dependency in build path, but the folder did not exist. NPE went away after I removed the dependency.

Guess it would be a good idea to check whether Build path entries are missing in any of the projects and resolve them to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The **Genuine solution** for this problem for windows OS is: **BY Setting up the path variable**

Easy 5 steps would be:

*STEP 0:* Goto Window button and click **Edit System Environment**

*STEP 1:* Goto Advanced>>Environment variables>>Edit PATH

*STEP 2:* Change path value as::

```
   **(1):** the jdk installed folder:- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin

   **(2):** copy the location of the path variable which is default i.e.: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd   

    **(3):** Merge both of them and paste/update into variable value as:- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin**;**%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

*STEP 3:* Open cmd by:- **ctrl+r**

*STEP 4:* Check for the current java version that you have installed for compliance to the machine by:- **java -version** (if it doesn't works, try:- **jshell -version**)

*STEP 5*: After getting the version launch eclipse IDE and create new java project and set the location of installed jdk as: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2

Thereafter, your java application would run efficiently.

***Why this problem arises:*** When we install multiple jdk and runs eclipse, our machine as well as eclipse ide need the synchronization of the java version installed. So, the solution is to change the path variable on the system and set ide java version as well.

Answer (score 0):

My .02c, and @madhuka-dilhan link helped to give inspiration, this was occurring every time I saved anything.  Two projects were causing it and it was super annoying, I had lived with it for about two months O_o

I was getting the following errors related to a bad Jackson jar file or two (but they work!) so I just disabled the two builders that were causing the error.  No more build errors anymore.  Note, not sure if this might have undesirable effects (yet).  Will update if it does!

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'JBoss Knowledge Base Builder' on project 'MSProvisioningMDBComplexOrderHandlerEJB'.
>   Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 10
>
> Errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project 'MSProvisioningMDBComplexOrderHandlerEJB'.
>   Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 10

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I had multiple JRE definitions of same version in:

Project -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Removing the unwanted ones resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these errors are due to external libraries not added properly.

1. Either remove unwanted libraries if you are able to narrow down the recently added one.
2. Else, create fresh workspace without adding new libraries and start using it.

In my case, lombok installation was causing the issue. Once it is removed, above build error issue was not coming.

See if that helps

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Problem on Eclipse under Linux.
When the battery of my notebook is empty, it turns off and close eclipse and all other running programs. After i boot my notebook again and starts eclipse, it shows my the message "Errors occurred during the build".
After i restart eclipse the problem goes from it self and it does not show again. 
Maybe the hard stop of eclipse is the cause.

Answer (score -1):

**Potential Fix:**

It is possible that the following files/directories were corrupted or don't pertain to your current workspace settings (importing someone else's project that has different configurations):

- `.classpath`
- `.project`
- `.settings/`

**Solution:**

1. Close the project
2. Close Eclipse
3. Move the above files/directories outside of the project directory (don't delete them just in case this isn't the problem)
4. Open Eclipse
5. Open the project

This should generate the `.project` and `.class` files at the least and you should no longer receive an error upon compilation. I hope this resolves your issue!